# Could not transform licenses file into a binary resource

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have my old `Web Applicatoin`, developed in `.Net Framework 2.0`. Now i am trying to open it in `VS2012` and it give me below error..

```
Could not transform licenses file into a binary resource.  (1) : error LC0004 :
Exception occurred creating type 'Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput.WebDateTimeEdit, 
Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput.v5.1, Version=5.1.20051.37, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: 
Unable to locate license assembly.at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.CreateWithContext(Type type, LicenseContext creationContext, Object[] args)
at System.Tools.LicenseCompiler.GenerateLicenses(String fileContents, String targetPE, ITypeResolutionService resolver, DesigntimeLicenseContext ctx)'
```

Answer (score 11):

Good afternoon,

This happened for me when we had branched a solution (svn) to be used to patch production should the need arise. When I built the solution from the branch, it gave me a similar error, talking about index based (zero) blah blah blah.. it turns out there was a blank line on my .licx file which was causing the error. Deleting the blank line fixed the issue.

Just posting in case this helps anyone else.

Update 2022-11-11: This no longer works for me in VS 2022. I now have to open the solution in VS 2019, empty the contents of that file and rebuild the solution, put the contents back and rebuild again. After doing that, I'm able to do a "Rebuild" in VS 2022. Please let me know if anyone finds a better solution to this, as I don't intend to keep VS 2019 on my machine forever =)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue. I was brain freezing over this one while it was such a simple fix. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I just came across this again, and my fix above did not work. To get it working this time, I deleted the contents of the file, rebuilt the solution, reverted my changes (putting the content back), and rebuilt the solution again.

Answer (score 3):

I have deleted the licenses file, and it worked for me

Comment: This answer worked for me for a DevExpress project

Answer (score 2):

Removed the extra line but it did not work.

I deleted the \BIN folder and did a "rebuild".  All is working now.

Answer (score -1):

I cut all the lines from licenses.licx and compiled the project, then I pasted the previously cut content into licenses.linx and recompiled the project and it works fine now.